# Как с помощью rxJava отправлять на сервер запрос с некоторой периодичностью?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Использую retrofit2 в связке с rxJava2.Нужно с некоторой периодичностью обновлять некоторые данные, делая на сервер запрос.
Вот пример метода реализующего retrofit2

```
public Single<List<CategoryResult>> getCategory() {
    return serverAPI.getCategory();
}
```

Так вот, как мне отправлять на сервер этот запрос с периодичностью? Строго не судите, только начал осваивать rxJavа

Comment: Нужно данные на экране обновлять или, например, сохранять их в базу?

Comment: Сохранять в базе и обновлять на экране, мне бы узнать общую механику периодических действий, чтобы я мог применять ее для разнообразных ситуаций.

Comment: Механизм зависит от периодичности. Раз в 5 секунд это одно, раз в день - совсем другое. Какой случай у вас?

Comment: раз в 30 секунд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Общая механика выглядит следующим образом.
Вам нужно создать `Service`, который будет выполнять фоновую задачу, при вызове:

```
public class SyncService extends IntentService {

    private MyRepository repository;

    private ServerAPI serverAPI;

    private Disposable subscription;

    public SyncService(MyRepository repository, ServerAPI serverAPI) {
        super(SyncService.class.getName());

        this.repository = repository;
        this.serverAPI = serverAPI;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
        subscription = serverAPI.getCategory()
                .flatMapCompletable(new Function<List<CategoryResult>, Completable>() {
                    @Override
                    public Completable apply(List<CategoryResult> categoryResults) throws Exception {
                        return repository.saveOrUpdate(categoryResults);
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(
                        new Action() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() throws Exception {
                                WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
                                // Данные в базе обновлены, можно что-то ещё сделать
                            }
                        },
                        new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                // Где-то случилась ошибка. Логируем, проверяем, что-то делаем
                            }
                        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // При уничтожении завершаем все операции
        if (subscription != null) {
            subscription.dispose();
            subscription = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Тут я полагаю, что у вас есть какой-то репозиторий со схожим интерфейсом

```
public interface MyRepository {

    Completable saveOrUpdate(List<CategoryResult> categoryResult);
}
```

Далее, нужно создать таймер, который будет запускать сервис.

Рекомендую почитать документацию по этому вопросу https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.

```
public class SyncAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, SyncService.class);
        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context, Long interval) {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncAlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, interval, interval, pendingIntent);
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootCompletedReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        if (alarmManager != null && pendingIntent != null) {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootCompletedReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

И ещё `BroadcastReceiver` для перезапуска таймера при включении устройства:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private SyncAlarmReceiver alarm = new SyncAlarmReceiver();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            if (*some condition*){
                alarm.setAlarm(context, *тут нужно передать переодичность задачи*);
            } else {
                alarm.cancelAlarm(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы получать сообщения о запуске устройства нужно добавить в манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Ну и чтобы руками запустить/перезапустить таймер с заданным интервалом:

```
SyncAlarmReceiver alarm = new SyncAlarmReceiver();
alarm.cancelAlarm(context);
alarm.setAlarm(context, *интервал*);
```